# Best way of converting a UInt256 into a UFix64 in Cadence without losing precision

Tags: smartcontracts, onflow-cadence

So I'm working on the port of the BandProtocol oracle contract to Cadence.

Their standard way of presenting the rate data is multiplied by [e18](https://docs.bandchain.org/products/band-standard-dataset/using-band-standard-dataset/contract#getreferencedata).

In the [cadence version](https://github.com/onflow/band-oracle-contracts/blob/2b6836ec5f20635fa5f5f22f4b72f5ec59f4455c/contracts/BandOracle.cdc#L70), we want to provide an additional field on the struct that will have the information in fixed point format for easier consumption by other cadence contracts.

I'm wondering if there is a best way of doing that, I believe there will be two potential ways, considering `pub let e18: UInt256 = 1000000000000000000`:

`UFix64(rate/e18)` or `UFix64(rate)/UFix64(e18)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this, covers all UFix64 I guess

`UFix64(rate /  1_000_000_000_000_000_000) + UFix64((rate/10_000_000_000) % 100_000_000) / 100_000_000.0`

https://run.dnz.dev/snippet/4f5342c367eb2db5